# Como separar los primeros numeros de un caracter SQL o Rstudio

Tags: sql, rstudio

Tengo una duda si es posible en sql o Rstudio sacar de los productos los números subrayados en rojo ya que es un carácter el campo y para crear otra columna que se llamada cantidades  tal como se ve en la imagen .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Hola les mando los codigos siguientes , disculpen la demora :

```
select * from caracteres
insert into caracteres values ('agua x 10mll')
insert into caracteres values ('agua x 10mll x12mg')
insert into caracteres values ('Caja recursos x 20 x 10ml')
insert into caracteres values ('Caja x 30 x 10ml')
insert into caracteres values ('agua x 23mg x11g')
insert into caracteres values ('Cajasa x 3021 x 10ml')


CREATE FUNCTION split(val VARCHAR(255), del VARCHAR(255), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, del, pos),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, del, pos-1)) + 1), del, '');

select * from caracteres

select nombretabla , left(nombretabla, CHARINDEX(' ', nombretabla)) as primerfiltro,

substring(nombretabla, CHARINDEX(' ', nombretabla)+1, len(nombretabla)-(CHARINDEX(' ', 
nombretabla)-1)) as segundofiltro,

substring(substring(nombretabla, CHARINDEX(' ', nombretabla)+1, len(nombretabla)-(CHARINDEX(' ', 
nombretabla)-1)), CHARINDEX(' ', substring(nombretabla, CHARINDEX(' ', nombretabla)+1, len(nombretabla)-(CHARINDEX(' ', 
nombretabla)-1)))+1, len(substring(nombretabla, CHARINDEX(' ', nombretabla)+1, len(nombretabla)-(CHARINDEX(' ', 
nombretabla)-1)))-(CHARINDEX(' ', 
substring(nombretabla, CHARINDEX(' ', nombretabla)+1, len(nombretabla)-(CHARINDEX(' ', 
nombretabla)-1)))-1)) as tercer

from caracteres
##
select * from caracteres
select len(nombretabla)-(CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla)-1) from caracteres

select CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla) from caracteres
##
select * from caracteres

select CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla) from caracteres -- +1
--select len(nombretabla) from caracteres
--select len(nombretabla)-(CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)-1) from caracteres 

select * from caracteres
select CHARINDEX(' x', nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla)+1) from caracteres -- -1 para que el valor 30 o el numero
select len(nombretabla) from caracteres


select SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla)+1,CHARINDEX(' x', nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla)+1)-1) 
from caracteres
where nombretabla <> 'Cajas recursos x 100'



select SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla)+1,LEN(nombretabla)) 
from caracteres
where nombretabla <> 'Cajas recursos x 100'


select SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla)+1,CHARINDEX(' x', nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x ', nombretabla)+1)-1) 
from caracteres







---------------------------------------------------------------------------------



select SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)) 
from caracteres

--
select CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla))) from caracteres

--
select CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla))) from caracteres
where CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla))) > 0 


select *,left(SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)),
            CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)))) from caracteres
where CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla))) > 0 


select nombretabla ,CASE    
            WHEN  CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla))) > 0 
             THEN left(SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)),
                    CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)))-1) --le ponemos menos aca porque sino estaria los numero un espacio mas

             ELSE SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)) 

             END
             FROM caracteres



--
drop table #caracteres1

select nombretabla ,CASE    
            WHEN  CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla))) > 0 
             THEN left(SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)),
                    CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)))-1) --le ponemos menos aca porque sino estaria los numero un espacio mas

             ELSE SUBSTRING (nombretabla,CHARINDEX('x', nombretabla)+2,LEN(nombretabla)) 

             END as cantidf
             into #caracteres1
             FROM caracteres 

--
select *,ISNUMERIC(cantidf) as evaluador into #caracteres2 from #caracteres1

select * from #caracteres2
--


    UPDATE #caracteres2
    SET cantidf = 1 
    WHERE evaluador = 0

    select * from #caracteres2
    -----------------------
```

Comment: ¿Cuál manejador de base de datos utilizas (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)? Dependiendo de eso, la solución varia por la sintaxis de cada producto. La solución es posible en cualquier producto.

Comment: Ya lo solucione en parte en SQL , pero hay una lógica mi nueva pregunta seria en vez que sea 20 en el producto , aparezca 20u como pasar eso a 20 , ya pude sacar todas las cantidades pero hay productos con esa característica "u" (unidad) , suponiendo que tengas 100 registros.

Comment: Rodrigo, por empezar define por medio de las etiquetas, como lo quieres resolver ¿en R? ¿en sql? si es este último ¿que motor usas? y por último ¿podrías compartir una muestra de casos representativos en texto y no como imagen? Saludos